# How to control Spark JavaRDD<MyTable> to take specific n rows?

Tags: apache-spark

I am having my own data structure called `MyTable` which is kind of columnar data store format table. Now I want to use Spark to create `myTable` in distributed environment as my datasets are in HDFS. I have used Spark earlier and I am familiar with it.

I am not able to figure out how can we control JavaRDD to take n rows. Here n could be 80k, 90k rows etc. If you see the following JavaRDD will always create one row MyTable, how do I create MyTable with n rows

```
JavaRDD<MyTable> rdd_records = sc.textFile("/path/to/hdfs").map(
      new Function<String, MyTable>() {
          public MyTable call(String line) throws Exception {
             String[] fields = line.split(",");
             Record record = create Record from above fields 
             MyTable table = new MyTable();
             return table.append(record);
      }
});
```

If I know how to command RDD to take certain no of rows then I can use it to create MyTable in distributed way.

Comment: two options that come to mind (but don't seem too reasonable) would be: 1) write your own RecordReader and use it to read several lines as a single input line and then split it in your spark task 2) zip the all the records with some value (i.e. counter % someVal), group/reduce by key and work on that

Comment: Hi @MateuszDymczyk I already have my own RecordReader but I can tell my client to provide their raw data to me in files with collection of rows they are coming as streaming data rows and gets stored in HDFS. I have one program which converts raw data into myTable but it is slow and I want to use Spark and hence I am here asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you load data using sc.textfile, spark automatically splits data on newlinesand puts them to partitions. So, what you need to do is a custom partitioning using your params (80k thing). Then you can use partitionBy on RDD. After that, you should be using mapPartitions instead of map to generate your data structures of Rows.

One advice, this seems a case to use Dataframes. If you are on 1.3, you take a look. It does converting tuples to schema in distributed way already